# ADAL.JS Support for multiple authentication with WAAD and ADFS onpremise

Tags: adal, adal.js

I want to authenticate multi tenant application against users from Windows Azure Active Directory and ADFS onpremise from single page application, Is this possible using ADAL.JS

As we call the init() method of ADAL.JS with few parameters

1. instance
2. Tenant
3. clientid

Now these 3 parameters will be different in case of Azure Active Directory anf ADFS onpremise.

Is this possible using ADAL.JS?

Comment: @vibronet, any inputs on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADAL.js to authenticate with one identity provider(either AAD or ADFS) at a time by setting the instance parameter to that identity provider endpoint.

If you want to support authentication with both AAD and ADFS accounts in the same app, you will need to set up a federation of user accounts in ADFS with AAD and then you can just point Adal.js to the AAD endpoint.

Comment: Yes correct, at a time one instance parameter is supported, i was able to reinitialize the adal service by fetching the instance details based on current logged in user, with this i was able to initialize adal js with multiple instances as per user